# Tricolor graph algorithm and constness

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, constants

In order to do a topological sort, I need to apply the tricolor algorithm[1] on a graph. That is, assuming the vertices are WHITE, the algorithm would be implemented like

```
void visit(Vertex& v)
    {
    v.color=GRAY;
    auto child=v.children.begin();
    auto v_end=v.children.end();
    while(child!=v_end)
        {
        if(child->color==GRAY)
            {throw "Loop detected";}
        if(child->color==WHITE)
            {visit(*child);}
        ++child;
        }
    v.color=BLACK;
    }
```

Now, i want the algorithm to not modify `v`, so it can be `const` without `mutable`. What is the most efficient way to make this work? Some ideas are

- Copy the graph before processing it
- Use an `std::map<Vertex*,color_type>`
- Give each vertex an id during a preceding pass, such the ids corresponds to the order which the vertices was visited. Then the color can be stored in an array.

[1] http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs2112/2012sp/lectures/lec24/lec24-12sp.html

Comment: You want to modify AND not-to modify - both?

Comment: I want to keep track of the three states without modifying `v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by giving each node in the graph an id during construction. Then, I used a temporary array when sorting the graph. Complexity:

- Two additional operation during construction (retrieve the node count and assigning the id). Constant time.
- One array lookup in order to get the vertex color. Constant time

Thus no additional complexity.